# iOS 8 CGAffineTransformConcat with Scale and Translate cause a position jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am having an issue with CGAffineTransformConcat that is present in iOS 8, but not iOS 7.  When animating a UIView using a concatenation with a scale and translate causes the position to jump.  Running the same code in iOS 7, achieves the desired results.  Is there something that has changed that causes this issue?

Here is my example code...

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //add a view
    self.lilView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    self.lilView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.lilView];

    //add a tap gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(poop:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void) poop:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) gesture {
    if (!self.pooped) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

        self.lilView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200, 300));

        self.pooped = YES;

    } completion:nil];

} else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

        self.lilView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 200));

        self.pooped = NO;

    } completion:nil];

}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Autolayout and transforms?

Comment: I turned off auto layout in my View Controller and my UIView was created programmatically so I don't think it has any constraints on it

Comment: Have you tried using valid options when animating?

Comment: Yes I've tried beginFromCurrentState, allowAnimatedContent, layoutSubviews, and even AllowUserInteraction just incase with no effect.

Comment: If I set the center of the UIView and just use a CGAffineTransformMakeScale, everything works they way it should.  I'm not sure, but CGAffineTransformConcat may be buggy in iOS8.

Comment: I've run into a very similar issue recently only on ios8 by having an initial rotation transform on a view, then later applying a scale transform on top of it (which uses the concat method underneath I believe). The resulting position and size winds up correct at the end of the animation but the animation starts by first jumping (no animation) to the final position and size, then shrinks itself (animated) and finally animates back to the correct location and size. no solution found yet for that. auto layout is not a factor here either.